# Pimcore Workflow Management

Tags: pimcore

I'm tring to set up example workflow management in default pimcore instalation and I don't know where should I start.
I understand states, configs etc. but where is in pimcore panel placee when I could do something with object or asset?

Now I have default config workflow from example config, and in my documents is information about state (TO DO). How could I do somothing?

Do you know some tutorials of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good to see you're experimenting with Workflow Management. I've written some introductions to the feature, they're available here:

Part 1 - Basic Introduction
https://www.gatherdigital.co.uk/community/post/pimcore-workflow-management-pt1/66

Part 2 - How to configure Actions
https://www.gatherdigital.co.uk/community/post/pimcore-workflow-management-pt2/67

Part 3 - How to extend actions using Events
https://www.gatherdigital.co.uk/community/post/pimcore-workflow-management-pt3/70

To get you going, there is an example in configuration directory in Pimcore

All actions that can be carried out are in the Elements themselves, so in the case of Documents, if your workflow is configured correctly you will see a button called "Actions" in the edit view. Clicking actions will show a the action panel.

Cheers!
Paul

Comment: I'm really blind!
I have read your instructions, are great! Thank you.
Now I just didn't see "Action" button..

Answer (score 0):

Below workflow plugin is also very useful to create workflow from UI.

https://github.com/dpfaffenbauer/pimcore-WorkflowGUI

1. Download the zip
2. Upload Tools -> Extensions -> Upload Plugin (zip file)
3. Click on Enable (+) symbol.

Once upload, workflows can be seen under settings. (Setting -> Workflows). The workflow created will be added to workflowmanagement.php in website/config folder. (Tools -> System Info & Tools -> Server File Explorer).